# Readably modify elements located deeply in nested lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I'm during some machine learning stuff which often involves iterating over several variables to find the best model hyperparameters. Therefore, my information about how a model performed for a certain combination of settings is located within lists of lists of lists.

Now let's say I want to retrieve some information and use it to calculate new values at this level in the list.

```r
# create an element to modify deep within a list
predictions <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
actual <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)

# compare predictions against actual values with a confusion matrix
confusion_matrix <- table(
  factor(predictions, 
         levels = min(predictions) : max(predictions)),
  factor(actual, 
         levels = min(actual) : max(actual)))
confusion_matrix

# create a nested list
my_list <- list(
  first_layer = (
    list(
      second_a = list(
        third = list(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix)), 
      second_b = list(
        third = list(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix)), 
      second_c =list(
        third = list(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix))
)))

str(my_list, max = 4)

# get the individual entries of the confusion matrix and store them in a 
# list on the same level named "Prediction_cases" to calculate Error types later
for (aa in seq_along(my_list)) {
  for (bb in seq_along(my_list[[aa]])) {
    for (cc in seq_along(my_list[[aa]][[bb]])) {
      print(my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]])
      my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["Prediction_cases"]] <- list(
        True_negative = my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]][1,1], 
        False_negative = my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]][1,2], 
        False_positive = my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]][2,1], 
        True_positive = my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]][2,2]
      )
      # it becomes even more fun with dynamic adressing
      print(my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]][2,length(my_list[[aa]][[bb]][[cc]][["confusion_matrix"]][,2])])
    }
  }
}

str(my_list, max = 4)
```

This works perfectly fine, but you can see, as deeper as it goes, the more indices are required. Is there a better way to do this or a more concise way to write this for

a) the definition within the for loop (`for (cc in seq_along(my_list[[aa]][[bb]]))`)

b) within the body of the loop?
?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
purrr::flatten(my_list)
```

Comment: Hey Georgery, thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't know how to make use of a flat list to achieve my goals, i.e. to modify elements at a certain depth?